# PushPlugin is not working after upgrading to cordova 3.1.0

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, push-notification

After Cordova upgrading to 3.1.0, onNotificationGCM function event = register cannot been called. So I can get push notification for the registered phone, but new phone cannot be registered.

Checking console of ATD, I got this:

```
W/PluginManager(31200): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to PushPlugin.
register blocked the main thread for 30ms. Plugin should use
CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

Anyone has same problem and could give some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found somehow gWebView.sendJavascript(_d); is not running in **sendJavascript** function in **PushPlugin.java**. It could PushPlugin error or Cordova error.

```
    /*
     * Sends a json object to the client as parameter to a method which is defined in gECB.
     */
    public static void sendJavascript(JSONObject _json) {
            String _d = "javascript:" + gECB + "(" + _json.toString() + ")";
            Log.v(TAG, "sendJavascript: " + _d);

            if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
                    gWebView.sendJavascript(_d); 
            }
    }
```

Change `gWebView.sendJavascript(_d);`(line 105) to **gWebView.loadUrl(_d)** will fix problem.

Comment: hello wen, still its not working in my project for the same error.. Any idea ? Please help..

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your project? Can you get Log.v(TAG, "sendJavascript: " + _d); message in your console?

Comment: error removed now but I am not getting registration Id as ecb callback isnot being run

Comment: can you tell me how can I get google registration id with this plugin ?

Comment: In GCMIntentService.java line34, could you get Log.v(TAG, "onRegistered: " + json.toString()); message in your console? If you could get this, that mean you already get device reg_id. Try to use real device to do the testing.

Comment: When I replace gWebView.sendJavascript(_d);(line 105) by gWebView.loadUrl(_d) my android app crash...

Comment: same error tried this solution but still same on android 4.0.4

Comment: @motto This solution is working on Android 4.2. Could you try to update your Android version and try it again?