# PushPlugin /cordova onnotificationgcm not being fired

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

Hi i'm working on notification push with Cordova/Ionic and i try to get the registration Id of the device (i tried with my phone and simulator) the problem is when the device ready being called the SuccessHandler return success 'Ok'but onNotificationGCM not being fired, my project id is correct and Google Cloud Messaging for Android api is activated in the google cloud console and Internet is also activated in my mobile and i have network access permission in my app android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

THANKS

Comment: Hey it's me again, i solved the problem without any foreign help, the problem was in my project plugins so : first i removed my android platofrm with `cordova platform remove android` second i remove the plugin with `cordova plugin rm THE_PLUGIN` and to know the name of the plugin `cordova plugin ls` third i add my plugin (pushplugin) with `cordova plugin add THE_PLUGIN`. I build my app and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound very blind but it happened to me today, the plugin was working and all of the sudden it stopped working. Turns out my phones wifi was turned off. For other people experiencing this issue. The following steps should work.

- As OP mentioned clear platforms + plugins.
- (install the plugin)phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
- you will also need the device plugin installed - phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
- phonegap run android

If your phone has connectivity and is found the app should run on the phone and you will be able to get the registration id.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cordova 3.1 like me and you can't rebuild the android project you can try the solution mentioned here [PushPlugin is not working after upgrading to cordova 3.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801101/pushplugin-is-not-working-after-upgrading-to-cordova-3-1-0).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms but obviously a different problem.

Check that your `senderID` ist actually your Google **Project Number** and not your *Project ID*. It should only contain numbers.